# Setting scheduled push notification on GCM Server

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to set up a Scheduled Push notification from the GCM server.

**Example:**

As I click a button i send an api call to the GCM server to send me a push after 30min.

Is that possible?

If yes, please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. GCM server attempts to deliver the messages you send to it immediately.

If you want to schedule a message for delivery at a given time, schedule it in your server. i.e. make your server send it to GCM server after 30 minutes.